# Three Layer PN Junction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, potential, semiconductor-physics, electronics

I am dealing with a PN junction which consists of these 3 layers:

An N-doped region with $N_D=5\times10^{18}cm^{-3}$

A lightly P-doped region with $N_{Al}=1\times10^{15}cm^{-3}$ with a thickness of $2\mu m$

An P-doped region with $N_A=3\times10^{18}cm^{-3}$

I am supposed to find the built in voltage ($V_{bi}$) for the diode and the applied voltage at which the lightly P-doped region is fully depleted.

Now for a normal PN junction I know I can find $V_{bi}$ by integrating the carrier density (eg. the electrons n) from one region to the other:
$$\int_{n_{p0}}^{n} \frac {dn}{n} = \frac {q}{kT}\int_{V_p}^{V_n} dV$$
Which yields:
$$V_{bi}=V_n-V_p=\frac {kT}{q}\ln\left(\frac{n}{n_{po}}\right)=\frac {kT}{q}\ln\left(\frac{N_A N_D}{n_i^2}\right)$$

Where $n_i$ is the intrinsic carrier concentration. What I'm not sure about is how the presence of the 3rd dopant (lightly P-doped region) affects this procedure. I'd appreciate any help with that.

Comment: Contemplate how you would do it if the lightly doped region were actually intrinsic. Or if the thickness of the lightly doped layer is sufficient to contain the depletion region all by itself (haven't run the numbers myself). Don't blindly apply formulas, understand them.

Comment: If I wanted to treat the region as intrinsic how might I go about that? PIN diodes are not something I have covered yet and information I have looked up on it is quite sparse.